# How to tell which OAuth Tokens returned in Google Adwords and Analytics APIs

Tags: oauth, google-analytics-api, access-token, google-ads-api

I have my OAuth process working well, I have an application that requires Google Adwords and Google Analytics access tokens. For whatever reason, Google has made these separate in terms of acquiring OAuth tokens. I know there is limited capability of using the Analytics tokens to access an Adwords account, but this requires the user to actively connect their two accounts, and even then access is limited. I have the user redirected away to authenticate with Google and when they come back I have their token and token secret.

One main functionality I need to impose is the user must be able to authenticate one account, and just use that. Or authenticate both accounts (analytics and adwords) and be able to use the two in tandem, with the tokens stored separately.

My main question is this: how can I figure out which oauth token has been returned? Currently, I have the oauth process located on two separate pages (two seperate callback urls, one for analytics and one for adwords), but I want to make them on the same page, and I've realized that they both return oauth_token & oauth_token_secret. Has anybody come across this before? How did you decipher between the two when the callbacks are located on the same page?

What's the best practice for this situation? It's not the end of the world, if I have to authenticate the user for each service on two separate pages, but would like to know that I have tried to implement something like this :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you should have a separate callback page for each service. It's simpler and easier to keep the tokens separate.